# Trouble logging into my web application with google oauth2.

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I am having trouble signing into my web application. I am using oauth2 for sign in. After signing in with my gmail account it just brings me back to a blank white page with a google sign in button on the top left corner. the url reads: localhost:8000/login  In my google api console I tried editing the authorized redirect URIs. And as well in the json file. But it doesn't seem to do anything. How do I direct the oauth2 login to the correct webpage after signing in?

console.developers.google.com/apis

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 0.0.0.0 from the Authorized JavaScript origins in the google developer console.

Used Authorized JavaScript origins: http://localhost:8000 
Authorized redirect URIs: http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback

And I added the GET method in addition to the POST method. @app.route('/gconnect', methods=['POST','GET']) in my application file. This worked for me.